# Is there any special way to remark and format using markdown a summary in a very large question?

Tags: discussion, questions, markdown

Although the title should summarize the content of a question, sometimes it is hard to synthesize the whole question in just a sentence.

It would be very interesting if there is any standard way to provide it. Taking into account accessibility principles, questions in Stack Exchange should be written in an easy and plain English, understandable for everyone, avoiding the using of jargon terms like `TL;DR`.

So my question is: Using [markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), what is the best way to format and remark a summary to a question?

Maybe the next approach could be correct?

> Using [markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), what is the best way to format and remark a summary to a very large question?

Comment: what do you mean? What exactly are you asking? How to write a tdlr;? What's [tag:markdown] got to do with this?

Comment: I mean the right way to write down and remark, using markdown syntax, the summary of a very large question.

Comment: Cross-post on MSE: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295262/what-is-the-best-way-to-write-a-technical-summary-to-question

Comment: Interesting... 3 years: +20/-3 vs. +0/-7

Comment: much better edit! :) +1 cc: @ShadowWizard

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250415/do-we-need-a-new-markdown-formatting-for-indented-boxed-text-for-preambles-r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not, you should either narrow down the question, or use paragraphs in your question to split the various sections. One of those sections could be `Summary`, or the commonly used `tldr;`.

The markdown engine doesn't support anything like this, and in my opinion it shouldn't. I think it is important to make the question as condensed as possible. If that still produces a long question, create sections as described above.